# Building a Fantasy Football App. If player name is not in JSON data file, set score to zero. Sounds simple, but how do I get it to work?

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-forms

I'm building a very simple fantasy football web-app using django for a course. One bug I discovered recently was that if a player isn't present in the JSON data that I'm pulling from an api, then it throws an error stating that the local variable for that player's score is being referenced before being assigned. Makes sense given that there is no actual data for that player. So, to fix this, I figured all I needed to do is add an elif (or else) statement to my logic to set that player's score to zero. Here's my code for this so far.

```
for score in scores:
    if score['player_name'] in QBname:
    QBscore = float(score['points'])
    totalpoints.append(QBscore)
```

I'm looping through a list called "scores" where I have the player scores coming in from an api call, then I'm comparing the player's name, which is stored in a variable called "QBname", to score['player_name]. Obviously, if score['player_name'] is a match and is in "QBname", I'm then appending that player's score to the variable "totalpoints." Now, to "fix" the problem, and assign a score of 0 to an absent player, I thought I would need something like this...

```
 if score['player_name'] in QBname:
    QBscore = float(score['points'])
    totalpoints.append(QBscore)

 elif score['player_name'] not in QBname:
      QBscore = 0
      totalpoints.append(QBscore)
```

However, it just overrides the player's actual score by setting it to zero. I've tested it out by adding the elif line to other players who definitely are present and have a score, but yeah, overrides it. I tried an else statement also which was similar, but same result.

So, this seems like a pretty straightforward problem to fix, but I keep going wrong and would really appreciate another set of eyes on it, so to speak. I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Is `QBscore` used anywhere else after this, and is there a reason you are setting it to 0 and then appending to `totalpoints` rather than just calling `totalpoints.append(0)`?

Comment: Good point @DragonBobZ. I tried out your suggestion by just doing totalpoints.append(0) as QBscore isn't actually used again after this. It solves the problem of not overriding a player's score with 0, but django is still throwing an UnboundLocalError for a player who is absent from the data.

Comment: I think it would help if you showed more code. One unrelated thing that stands out to me, is that you probably want `score["player_name"] == QBname`, rather than `score["player_name"] in QBname`. Using `in` in this context means, you're searching for the presence of a substring in another string. This has the undesirable side-effect of potentially treating two distinct players as the same player. For example, if `score['player_name']` is `"Bob"`, and `QBname` is `"Bobby"`, you would enter the body of the if-statement, because the substring `"Bob"` is present in `"Bobby"`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @PaulM. Indeed it was an easy fix after all. After a while I realized that I just needed to set the QBscore variable higher in the order as it was being referenced before being assigned. I gave myself an uppercut after realizing how easy it was to fix.